# How to insert batch of 1000 records into db?

Tags: scala, bulkinsert, slick

I'm reading a huge file and inserting records in mysql using `statement.executeBatch()` of prepared statement. Below is the code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {

      count += 1
      statement.setString(1, record.id)
      statement.setString(2, record.date)
      statement.setString(3, record.msg)
      statement.addBatch()

      if (count % 1000 == 0) 
          statement.executeBatch()
}
statement.executeBatch()
```

How can Slick help here (perhaps mimicking the code above)?

Comment: Double posted at: https://groups.google.com/d/msgid/scalaquery/2ae99f85-2fba-4d29-8709-4ddbda799a8e%40googlegroups.com?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using Slick 2.0.2

Once you have a case class modeling your data, your Table class and your TableQuery object defined, just read the file into a Seq, and add it to the TableQuery object using the ++= function.

```
case class MyDataClass(id: String, date: String, msg: String)

class MyData(tag: Tag) extends Table[MyDataClass](tag,"mydatatableInDB") {
   def id = column[String]("id")
   def date = column[String]("date")
   def msg = column[String]("msg")

   def * = (id, date, msg) <> (MyDataClass.tupled)(MyDataClass.unapply)
}

val myDataTableQuery = TableQuery[MyData]

// read your data into a Seq[MyDataClass] (for example) and...

myDataTableQuery ++= listWithData
```

If you really need to do it with a batch, you could group the elements using grouped, and iterate on them, adding data to the table query on each iteration. Something like this:

```
// With your data already in a Seq
def insertIntoTableQuery(data: List[MyDataClass) = {
    myDataTableQuery ++= data
}

// make groups of 1000 and iterate    
listWithData.grouped(1000) foreach insertInToTableQuery
```

Unless I'm missing something, I think this is pretty much covered in the documentation:

[Slick 2.0.2 Documentation](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.2/gettingstarted.html)

Some weeks ago I had a similar task. The file I was working with had 350,000+ lines, and from each line I had to extract data and create a couple of objects, each of one was to be inserted in a different table. Mind you, I didn't need to do it in a batch and it was really fast.

Comment: Hello I have used the same solution. Actually I have created an actor to insert record in database.DB actor's receive() method receives one record at a time ,It stores it in list, when size of list becomes 1000 i m inserting it into Mysql using batch insert..  but if database doesn't support the batch insert then what wud be the proper way?? inserting one record at a time not efficient??  Thanks

Comment: I'm not an expert in Slick, but it seems to me that you're trying to bulk insert in a more complicated way. In my case, I had no speed nor performance issues when inserting those 350,000 registers (creating a couple of objects for each of them), and didn't use batch insert, just the normal ++= function. If performance is an issue for you, and you don't need to pre-process the data before inserting it into the database, maybe you can achieve better results using mysql directly (load data infile).